# How to find area of a curve in python where coordinates are not known?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

So I am currently working on a project where I need to find the area in terms of cm of a particular curve.The problem is the curve has more than one colors each representing a different values 
[Something Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIezg.png)

Can someone help me do it? There are more than one such curves in the image. How to simultaneously calculate all of them in Python.

Comment: please add more details: what is the input format, what is the expected result, what have you tried so far and why it did not work

Comment: Is that low quality picture all you have? No scale, dimensions, other information? Then you will have insufficient data to calculate any absolute value.

Comment: Can you frame your question more clearly ? You mean area in terms of cm^2 of all the colored blobs in it ?

Comment: Which curve do you want? Here is the max region contour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8iJX.png

Comment: Yes i need to find the area in terms of cm^2 of the color blobs according to the image.The image has a scale of 1 cm=10 km @I.Newton

Comment: Thank you @Silencer ill try to do that. Can you share your code for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to print area in terms of pixels. To get the area in cm^2, you need to know the relationship between pixels and actual length.

The following code prints the area of largest blob in the image. 
To get the area of all the blobs in the image, just replace `[c]` with `contours`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 


img = cv2.imread("image.png", 0)
blank = np.zeros_like(img)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0 ,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if( len(contours) != 0 ):
    c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    cv2.drawContours(blank, [c], -1, 255, -1)
    print cv2.countNonZero(blank)

cv2.imshow("img", blank)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edit:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread("images.png", 0)
blank = np.zeros_like(img)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0 ,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i in range(len(contours)):
    cv2.drawContours(blank, contours[i], -1, 255, -1)
    print "area of contour " + str(i)+" = " + str(cv2.contourArea(contours[i]))
    cv2.imshow("img", blank)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for this.how do i find the area of all contours??? And display each area individually??

Answer (score 0):

1, separate out the different colored blobs. They look like they are generated by some other mapping software so presumably the colors are fixed and known. Make a new image for each color

2, For an image that contains only blobs of a fixed color and a black background you can make contours of the outlines (see findContours). Opencv will give you a separate contour for each blob.

3, Calculate the area of each contour -there is an opencv function to do this.